# three sidebars showing without call

Tags: widgets, sidebar

code from template where i call header sidebar

```
<div class="wrapper">
<?php get_sidebar("header"); ?>
<div id="switcher">
```

widgets.php has following coding...

```
 <?php
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {

register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Header',
    'id'   => 'header',
    'description'   => 'This is the widgetized header.',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h4>',
    'after_title'   => '</h4>'
));
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Sidebar',
    'id'   => 'sidebar',
    'description'   => 'This is the widgetized sidebar.',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h4>',
    'after_title'   => '</h4>'
));
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Footer',
    'id'   => 'footer',
    'description'   => 'This is the widgetized footer.',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h4>',
    'after_title'   => '</h4>'
));

}
```

Comment: you want to display sidebar without call 'get_sidebar' right?

Comment: solved it...dynamic_sidebar();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was using get_sidebar() instead of dynamic_sidebar('name')....